# Предварительная загрузка изображений react

Tags: reactjs, img

У меня есть модальное окно, при его открытии изображения появляются на глазах у пользователя с видимой задержкой, как убрать эту задержку, чтобы при открытии сразу были видны изображения? Вот мой код. Прошу заметить, что изображения мне известны сразу, они не приходят с сервера, это обычные иконки через тег img

```
import one from './../../../../images/graphic/one.svg'
const GraphicModalSettings:React.FC<IModal> = ({active,setActive}) => {
const modes:IModes[]=[
    {q:1,mode:
        [
            {url:one, name:'one'}
        ]
    }]



return (
    <div className={styles.modes}>
         {modes[0].mode.map((m,index)=>(
            <div key={index} className={styles.modes_two} onClick={()=>chooseMode(m.name)}>
               <img src={m.url} className={mode?.name===m.name ? styles.activeMode : styles.mode} alt="" />
            </div>
          ))}
     </div>
)}
export default GraphicModalSettings
```